# SOAP is not handling properly when 'yyyy' is given in the field of year instead of proper year

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

There is an attribute of type datetime in the wsdl provided by client.
When a correct date of format 'yyyy-MM-dd' is entered everything is working fine.

But when 'yyyy' is given in the field of year, date similar to 'yyyy-01-01' is received by my java program. Result is i am getting a null value in my java program.

The soap ui is not returning any error message when it revives a wrong date.

Is this a restriction in soap ui?

Is there any way to handle above junk data ?

I am using methods of following packages to get the data from DTO(Data Transfer Object)

```
javax.xml.namespace.QName;
org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc;
org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc;
org.apache.axis.encoding.Deserializer;
org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer;
org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer;
org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer;
```

Comment: please add the code whatever you have tried so far

Comment: *"Result is I am getting a null value in my java program."* - Seeing your Java code, with where you're getting null clearly pointed out, would be helpful to finding a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to turn on "Schema Validation." Switch it on; it is usually off because it can impact performance.